# git rebase ignore conflicts

Tags: git, automation

I have a branch with lots (400+) of small, mostly independent, changes on it that were generated by a refactoring/linting tool.

I've used git bisect to isolate a commit that has caused a test failure.

I wish to rebase all of the commits after the offending one to just before it, effectively ignoring that suggestion.  However, some (usually less than 3) of the other commits will depend on that change.

Is there a way to tell rebase to just skip/ignore any commits that would conflict and keep the rest?

Comment: Just curious but how can a refactoring/linting tool cause a test to fail?

Comment: It's a little buggy and on my todo list.  It's good at flagging smells and usually ok at fixing them.

Comment: Currently, the only way to find out if something *would* cause a conflict in Git, is to try it out and see if it *does* cause a conflict. For a case like this I'd just let the thing run and manually skip or fix each conflicting change: if there are only going to be a few, might as well just deal with them. Andreas Louv's approach should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip a commit when rebasing with `git rebase --skip`.

A naive approach would to just skip all commits that is stopping the rebase:

```
while git rebase --skip; do :; done
```

The above is a small piece of shell code, that will execute the command line `git rebase --skip` until it fails.

It doesn't fail, when it cannot apply a change, but rather stops the rebase. It will however fail when you are not doing a rebase, which is the case when everything have been rebased.

`:` is just an empty command, doing nothing but exiting successfully. It's used because a while loop in shell scripts needs a body.